# Android compresses all the photos I see online

Tags: chrome-for-android, video, htc, images, google-drive

My HTC One M7 (ARHD 81.0) is compressing all the photos/videos I see online. Instagram? Compressed (even more than normal). Imgur on Chrome? Compressed. Photos from bacon reader? Compressed. Google Drive? Compressed. You name it and my phone will compress it. 
I was using opera max to cut down on my data usage but I removed it because I thought that it is the cause of my problem. 
Any ideas on how to get this fixed?

Comment: Is this over 3G or Wi-Fi?

Comment: Over 3g. I can't verify right now if it will be the same on Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 3):

The compression is actually performed by your carrier. Almost all mobile network carriers compress images to reduce bandwidth use on slow mobile connections.

You can avoid the compression by switching to a Wi-Fi network, or using an HTTPS connection to the website you want: since HTTPS is secured from interception, the carrier can't replace the pictures with its compressed versions.

Comment: Here's a good article on this topic: http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2013/mobile-isp-image-recompression/